# background-image doesn't appear if <div> is empty?

Tags: css, html

I created a `<div>` first thing in the `<body>` to draw a top line at the top of the page:

```
<body>
    <div class="bordertop"></div>
    .....
</body>
```

and the style:

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.bordertop {
    background-image: url(../images/top_border.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
}
```

However, the `top_border image` doesn't appear unless I write some text inside the `<div>` but I don't want to. How could I fix this?

Comment: Is the top border image something special?  Or could you style an `hr` tag instead?

Comment: If it's just a line, why not use `border-top:1px solid #000` ?

Comment: Yes it is special. It is a four-color line which will be repeated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since the div is empty, there's no content to push it "open" leaving the div to be 0px tall.  Set explicit dimensions on the div and you should see the background image.

```
.bordertop 
{
    background-image: url(../images/top_border.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%; /* may not be necessary */
}
```

Comment: An explicit height was enough in my case. Thanks :)

Comment: Specifying a width is only required when you also have position set to absolute.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to set the css `width` and `height` of your `<div>` element to whatever size you want

```
.bordertop {
    background-image: url(../images/top_border.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Setting an explicit height was enough.

Answer (score 2):

Give the `div` a `height:1px`. That should work. Otherwise your `div` is `0px` high, meaning you won't see anything.

You could also give it `padding-top:1px`

Another thing you could do is to set the `background-image` of the line on the `body` in your CSS. This is assuming the line is the entire width of the `body`.

See **[demo](http://jsbin.com/eseved/1/edit)**

Comment: Does 1 px really help??

Answer (score 0):

As the answers above me suggest ^^' it's because it has virtually no size, you need either to put content inside to resize it or to set width/height or padding in css bordertop class, or you can put another empty  inside it with set size. I was going to skip this answer since there are already answers but I just wanted to add that width/height is not your only option.

On a side note, oh man, people here posting so fast I sometimes wonder if its a race and what is the prize, there must be some, I guess helping other is itself great prize. :) When I was starting to type this there was no answer yet.

Comment: Thanks for your addition. You need to improve your typing speed bro ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is:
for landscape:

```
width:100%;
height:0;
padding-top:[ratio]%;
```

for portrait:

```
width:[ratio]%;
height:0;
padding-top:100%;
```

You need to determine which side is longer and accept this dimension as 100%
then calculate [ratio] - percentage of shorter dimension in relation to 100% longer dimension. Then use the one of solutions above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for quite some time, my solution was giving the style lines of: min-height. This opens the div to the height given if there is no elements inside. The height can get bigger with the more elements inside, but not smaller.

Example code:

```
.fixed-bg {

    /* The background image */
    background-image: url("img_tree.gif");
    /* Set a specified height, or the minimum height for the background image */
    min-height: 500px;
    /* Set background image to fixed (don't scroll along with the page) */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* Center the background image */
    background-position: center;
    /* Set the background image to no repeat */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Scale the background image to be as large as possible */
    background-size: cover;
}
```

code gotten from https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Answer (score 0):

If it is the only `div` element in the body use the following style to to make it occupy the full-width.

```
.bordertop  {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-image: 
   url('../images/top_border.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get my background showing in the div even with the width set up. Turns out i had to put "../" in the url section then it showed the picture i was struggling for quite a while.

```
left {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../img/loginpic.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    background-color: crimson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can just open a `<p></p>` and in styles, remove the default margin length, that's `margin: 0;` and add `height: 0.1px` which doesn't consume much space, so it'll work.

Note: it'll work properly until it's not zoomed out more than 50%, so make sure of the use case before you apply it to the body.