# Background-image inside div not showing up

Tags: html, css, image, background, positioning

So I was working on this site and I had the displaying how I was wanting.
After working on a lower page banner all of a sudden everything disappeared and all I was left with was the background Image in the Body.

Can you figure out why the topImage id does not display? It is frustrating as hell to see it work one second and then not the other:

```
<style>
   body
   {
   background-image:url("images/Background.gif");
   background-repeat:repeat-y;
   background-attachment:fixed;
   background-position:center top;
   }

   #topImage
   {
   position:absolute;
   background-image:url("images/Top-Banner.gif");
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   width:100%;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   }
</style>

<body>

    <div id="topImage"></div>

</body>
```

Sorry if this a really basic question, I am kind of new at this.

Comment: Please be a little more informative in your question title in future.

Comment: Will do, I couldn't figure out a better way to word "HELP!" sorry.

Comment: Related: [`background-image` doesn’t appear if `<div>` is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11963687/4642212).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#topImage` doesn't have a height set, and no elements inside it which would give it a height.

```
#topImage
{
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("images/Top-Banner.gif");
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px; /* Change to the height you need */
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

Or just stick an `img` tag inside the `div` instead of using `background-image`, that would work as well.

Comment: I tried that, and yet same result? Am I just retarded or is this just really messed up?

Comment: No, I cannot get it working in jsFiddle either. :S
Note: If I enter text between the div tags it shows in the appropriate position, whereas if I place an image either in the stylesheet or between the div tags it will not show. I can ensure the image is in the folder as I have checked.

Comment: For some reason it now works. What was wrong? I have no idea but something changed and now it works fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad to have been of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using the following syntax

```
#topImage
{
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("../images/Top-Banner.gif");
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px; /* Change it to auto if you need to div to adjust automatically according to contents inside it */
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

**hope that sorts out the problem**