# Background-image does not work locally or with external link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a background image for a project, and even when I use the Photobucket link(http://i1339.photobucket.com/albums/o714/garlandjon95/MovingMountains_zps5s3fqnf0.png) it still doesnt work. I have the image saved locally in a folder called images and it is called birds.png locally, yet still no image appears in my page.

HTML:

```
<body>

<h1>On The Fly Web Design</h1>
<p>Your needs on the fly</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-image:      url("http://i1339.photobucket.com/albums/o714/garlandjon95/MovingMountains_zps5s3fqnf0.png");
}
```

I've tried url(images/bird.png) but still nothing.

Comment: add heigth and width or add some content on that div

Comment: add height or type some text, or if you want to simply display the image without anything, add some padding top & bottom values

Comment: See [**Background-image inside div not showing up**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802383/background-image-inside-div-not-showing-up) or [**Background Image Not Displaying On Div**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836633/background-image-not-displaying-on-div) both referring to needing a height

Comment: Thank you guys! Much appreciated. I've also tried this targeting the body element and it did nothing as well.

Comment: Maybe your css file is in a folder? So, the css must be  background-image: url("../images/bird.png");

Comment: Actually, I forgot to link the stylesheet....

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the height or add content to the `div`. Try adding the background to the body and see the effect you get. Or add:

```
div{
   height:300px;
   width:300px;
   background-image: url("http://i1339.photobucket.com/albums/o714/garlandjon95/MovingMountains_zps5s3fqnf0.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing background image because the div to which you added the background image is empty. You need to either add some content to it or define its height and width.

You can check the snippet.

```css
div {
  background-image: url("http://i1339.photobucket.com/albums/o714/garlandjon95/MovingMountains_zps5s3fqnf0.png");
  height: 590px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>On The Fly Web Design</h1>
<p>Your needs on the fly</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add width and height to div.

```css
div{
width:100%;
height:400px;
background-image:url("http://i1339.photobucket.com/albums/o714/garlandjon95/MovingMountains_zps5s3fqnf0.png");
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>On The Fly Web Design</h1>
<p>Your needs on the fly</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because this div has no content inside, therefore the height is 0px and the background image will not show up. Try moving the div tags around the rest of your content, and also give it a class name which will help later on when you have multiple divs:

```
<body>

 <div class="page-content">
  <h1>On The Fly Web Design</h1>
  <p>Your needs on the fly</p>

  ...

 </div>

</body>
```

and then your css:

```
.page-content { 
  background-image: url("..."); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above explanation will work fine,if not kindly add few background property like background-size,background-position,repeat etc and also must add height