# Background-image is not working

Tags: css, background-image

**html**

```
<div id="home"></div>
```

**css**

```
#home{background-image:url("img/me.jpg");}
```

My code as above is not working. I checked that the folder "img" has the same location as my index.html as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background-image does not work locally or with external link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923866/background-image-does-not-work-locally-or-with-external-link)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div>` has no content and no dimensions (width/height).

Also, check the path. I would start from the root and built it from there. i.e. `/img/me.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the element a **width** and **height**. Also, your source path might be off. You should also add the following to control how the background image displays. Below will display an image 100% of the viewport height and 100% of its width. Essentially, full screen.

HTML

```
<div id="home"></div>
```

CSS

```
#home {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background:url('../img/me.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```