# Background Image Not Displaying On Div

Tags: html, css, background-image

For some reason, my website does not want to display the background-image which I have set on my div.

I want to have a featured image that display's across the whole page (kind of like on Microsoft's homepage). However, the image doesn't want to show.

I have tried disabling AdBlock and any other extensions with no avail, I have also tried to look on forums to see if I could find anything (which I haven't).

The following is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <div class="featured-img-display imgdisplay" data-lazyload="undefined" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="right center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-lazydone="undefined" src="/data/img/game_data/19a017f91q.jpg" data-src="/data/img/game_data/19a017f91q.jpg">

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And my 'relevant' CSS:

```
.container {
    left:15%;
    width:70%;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    padding:40px;
    width:90%;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-top:100px;
}
.featured-img-display{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('/data/img/game_data/19a017f91q.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ses3j1Ld/

Comment: Open Developer Tools (F12) and check for errors. One possible reason is not providing the correct url for background-image (I think the actual path is computed based on css location).

Comment: Did you check path to your file?

Comment: `height:100%` will result in zero height if the parent container has no height itself.

Comment: link to website or a fiddle?

Comment: Can you please provider the link of your website if its live? Or create a plunkr please. https://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: @Alexei already done this, no errors shown. Have also tried following the path to make sure that the image was there (and it was)

Comment: @Andrew yes I did...

Comment: @TarunDugar not available yet...

Comment: then can you create it in a plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: @TarunDugar https://jsfiddle.net/ses3j1Ld/

Comment: check your doctype declarations <!DOCTYPE>. if I set height to pixel seems working fine. but it was not good.

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic, So then you have to check your path again, because it tries to load your image with path, which is relative to your `css` file. Assume that you have `Content` folder and inside you have your `styles.css` file. It tries to load image looking through path `Content/data/img/game_data/19a017f91q.jpg`. Are you sure this is your path?

Comment: Related: [`background-image` doesn’t appear if `<div>` is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11963687/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the `featured-img-display` element has no height. That's why you don't see the background image.

`height: 100%;` will only set full screen height on an element if its parent actually has 100% screen height as well.

To do this using % units you'll need to make sure that all elements up to the `featured-img-display` element have 100% height,.. something like:

```
html,body,.container,.content {
     height: 100%
}
```

Then your current CSS code will work. Sometimes however the above code isn't so viable.

Using **viewport units** here: `height: 100vh;` makes things a lot easier

---

Note:

If you want the image to span the full screen height (and without scroll-bars), you'll have to adjust your CSS a bit:

1) remove default margin with `body { margin:0 }`

2) You have set padding and a border on the parent of the element with the background image... you'll probably want to set these properties on the image element itself with `box-sizing` set to `border-box`.

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/pgWQjr)

Comment: take a look at the demo :)

Answer (score 1):

the height of `.featured-img` is percentage value for make it work the parent's height must be determined and the only exception is the root element `html`, which can be a percentage height.

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
    left:15%;
    width:70%;
  height: 100%;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    padding:40px;
    width:90%;
  height: 100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-top:100px;
}

.featured-img-display{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="featured-img-display imgdisplay" data-lazyload="undefined" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="right center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-lazydone="undefined" src="/data/img/game_data/19a017f91q.jpg" data-src="/data/img/game_data/19a017f91q.jpg">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div, can you try with img tag as well. I think that might work

Comment: I'm using a div because I think It looks cleaner, as well as I would like to output code on top of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all your divs `.container`, `.content`, and `.featured-img-display` don't have a height. `height:100%` means having height equal to the element's parent but since none of those elements have any height, `height: 100%` equates to 0px. Same goes for width.

So, one of the divs will have to have a specific height and width. Here's an [example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldk60bhn/):