# Use css class to set ajax loader?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, loader

I have Ajax call and I would like to use `ajax-loader.gif` to show the loading process. I already have html span element that I use to display elements on the screen. I would like to add the loader in css class. Once ajax starts I would like to point to html element and add the class using `JQuery`, once ajax is done I will remove the class and hide the element. Here is the code that I tried to use but nothing showed up on the screen:

CSS:

```
.loader{
   background-image: url('Images/ajax-loader.gif');
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span>
    <span class="progressMsg" id="progressMsg"></span>
</span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.progressMsg').addClass("loader").show();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'my URL',
    data: myForm
}).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS === 200){
        $('.progressMsg').removeClass("loader").hide();
        return true;
    }else{
        $('.progressMsg').addClass('alert-box error').show().html('Error!');
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.progressMsg').removeClass("alert-box error").hide().html(""); }, 5000);
        return false;
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: Make sure `.progressMsg` has actual dimensions, and isn't 0 by 0 pixels

Comment: Yes the issue is that your containers do not have height and width defined. Set those properties and you will see your image.

Answer (score 1):

spans do not have space hen empty. You need to make it a block/inline-block and set dimensions.

```js
$('.progressMsg').addClass("loader").show();
```

```css
.loader{
   background-image: url('http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif');
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    <span class="progressMsg" id="progressMsg"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: diplay:inline-block was the key. After I placed that in my css loader showed up.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add heigth and width to element, otherwise it will have 0x0px and don't will shows nothing.

```
.loader{
    background:black url('images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #8ed9f6;
    heigth: 50%;
    width: 10px;
}
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963687/background-image-doesnt-appear-if-div-is-empty)

Comment: @epascarello I updated my question with the code that I tried to use but still nothing on the screen...

Comment: Well it is not my answer, but the issue is inilne elements do not have a width

Comment: @epascarello on .progressMsg class I set the width and height but still nothing showed on the screen.

Comment: yes, but an inline element does not have a width. spans do not have widths