# Why background image do not load?

Tags: css, background-image, gatsby, gatsby-image

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUsVJ.png)

My background image don't load! Can anyone tell what's happening? Is it because of gatsby? Should I use gatsby-image instead?

```
    background-image: url('/src/components/images/header.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

<div id="page">
     <div className='header'>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </div>  
     </div>
```

Comment: Does the div where you are giving background image contain any data or is it empty? If empty, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963687/background-image-doesnt-appear-if-div-is-empty

Comment: and don't use localhost in URLs else where you will make it live, you will have to change all with the domain name.

Comment: im not using localhost url ,  the browser assume localhost, i think thats why my image dont load

Comment: Does the div where you are giving background image contain any data or is it empty?

Comment: nop the div have a h1

Comment: plz add your code as a  fiddle like on https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

We don't really have your code so we don't know which code you are using. But we do know which code does work and it is the following:

```css
.header {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMDq.jpg?s=48&g=1");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

The main difference perhaps is that in the CSS I use double quotation marks.